# Delay in Thread execution+Android

Tags: android

After many trials of solutions (including posting questions on SO) I thouht will work fine. But no improvement. Coming to my problem, I am implementing an App that have a countdown timer. I am showing this on a button (Just using like a canvas by disabling the click event). 
I start the timer when user clicks a button (which is a separate button). Below is the countdown timer code,

```
public class DigitalTimer extends Button{

--------------------------------    
--------------------------------    
--------------------------------    
--------------------------------    
--------------------------------    
--------------------------------    
private String timerText;
public DigitalTimer (Context context,int hourstime,int mintime,int sectime){
    super(context);
    Log.d(TAG,"DigiTimer constructor");     
    this.context = context;     
    initialize(hourstime,mintime,sectime,timerType);
    setClickable(false);
}

public void initialize(int hourstime,int mintime,int sectime,int timerType){
    Log.d(TAG,"DigiTimer initialize");      
    this.hourstime = hourstime;
    this.mintime = mintime;     
    hour = hourstime;
    min = mintime;
    sec = sectime;

    //Just Thread version               
    **digiThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(!isPauseTimer()){
                updateTimes();
                SystemClock.sleep(UPDATEDELAY);
            }

        }           
    };**


    //Handler version       

    /*
    handleRunnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            updateTimes();
        }
    };
    */

}

private void updateTimes(){

    timerText = String.format(timerFormat,hour,min,sec );       
    postInvalidate(); 
    sec--;
    if(sec < 0){
        sec = 59;
        min--;
    }
    if(min < 0){
        min = 59;
        hour--;
    }   

    if(hour < 0){  //when hour is negative it means the given time completed so we stop the timer & alarm permanantely 
     hour = 0;
     min = 0;
     sec = 0;
          }

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d(TAG,"DigiTimer onDraw");      
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button9patch);     
    setText(timerText);     
}
public void startUpdateTheread(){
    //digiHandler.postDelayed(handleRunnable, UPDATEDELAY);
    **digiThread.start();**
}


private void startTimersAndAlarms(){
 -----------------------
 -----------------------
 -----------------------
 -----------------------
 **startUpdateTheread();**
 ---------------------
 ---------------------

}
```

}

Initially the timer is woking fine . **But if no.of hours for the countdown is higher (say 5:00:00) then its running fine until sometime (say 4:00:00) from then it is delaying the timer update**. (just to countdown a minute it is taking more time ..particularly when the user is out of the App)
    First I tried with the Handler. I had the problem. I thought the delay is because of keeping the UI thread busy. So I developed a separate thread. But still the problem persist.

Sorry for the long post. Please someone point what's happening. Is that something I am missing or putting the code in wrong place?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I read SystemClock.sleep documentation. It says "{This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input) }". I understand  that I should keep CPU on while I run this thread. So according to the answer by @Brandon I should implement partial POWERLOCK to keep the CPU on. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an accurate timer, I think you'll need to get a wake lock.

Check out the documentation of [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

You can either get a `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` to keep the screen on, or a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to keep the CPU running. Don't forget to add the permission to your AndroidManifest file too.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes. I already implemented the wake lock to kept the screen on. It is working. But my problem is to manage the countdown timer when the user exits the App. i.e. Assume the user exited (Home or Back button) the App when the timer shows 03:30:00 ... after 1 minute if the user goes back to the App it should show 03:31:00. It is showing this as well but sometimes a delayed time.